# Temporarily omitting a docker replica from load balancing without shutting down

Tags: docker

Say I have a docker service with two replicas, and I'd like one of these services to be out of commission for a while without actually stopping the container. Is it possible to connect to the docker socket (or other means) and inform it that this container is not available at the moment and that all requests should go to the other container in the replica set?

I.e. my replicas receive a heartbeat, and as a long as that heartbeat is coming in they should accept http connections. When a replica stops receiving a heartbeat, it should stop accepting connections until one is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what health checks are made for.

If the health check is not passed, the Swarm will not forward traffic to the container.